# Как добавить уведомление на экран блокировки

Tags: android

Как добавить уведомление на экран блокировки в Android. У меня есть уведомление, но его нужно добавить на экран блокировки, что нужно добавить в код? Вот мой код

```
    private static final String CHANEL_ID = "word_channel";
    private static final String CHANEL_NAME = "Word channel";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                        .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                        .setContentText("Пора покормить кота")
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setPriority(2);

        createChannels();
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
        notificationManager.notify(143, builder.build());
    }

    private void createChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            return;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANEL_ID, CHANEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174191/show-notifications-on-lock-screen) есть способ например. Так же есть [туториал](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-notifications-overview-94440ca7f120) по уведомлениям. В нем говорится что для того чтобы уведомление можно было показать на экране блокировки нужно менять `Visibility`:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Lock screen Notification")
    .setContentText("Really great content for this notification")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
```

Но код выше может давать доступ к неполному функционалу уведомлений, поэтому вот второй вариант:

```
val publicBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Alternative notification")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Lock screen Notification")
    .setContentText("Really great content for this notification")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
    .setPublicVersion(publicBuilder.build())
```

Comment: Уведомление все равно не показалось на экране блокировки

Comment: с учетом того что я не увидел того что у вас есть и то что вы сделали ничем кроме своих допущений помочь не могу :( Проверьте настройки приложения, возможно ему запрещён показ уведомлений.

Answer (score 0):

Уведомления не добавляются на экран блокировки разработчиком. Это делает система в зависимости от настроек пользователя, оболочки производителя и версии Android.

Вы можете воспользоваться ответом Andrew, чтоб создать нотификацию, она же и будет отображаться на экране блокировки.

Comment: Я проверил есть ли разрешения показа уведомлений у приложения, и оно есть.